# Question about akusala garuka kamma

Tags: karma

Is it called akusala garuka kamma only if the action is completed? For example,  Angulimala once tried to harm The Buddha (but did not succeed), and Nandopananda once tried to harm Moggallana Thera (also did not succeed). Their actions are not considered akusala garuka kamma because they did not succeed?

Comment: Duplicate of [The five incurable actions](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/44502/471)

Comment: Thank you. So from what I read in that question's answer, attempting to do something (there is an action) with the wrong intention is what caused karmic consequences?

Comment: If that's so, what about the case of Nandopananda? He attempted to harm an Arahant, no?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Nandopananda. It sounds like the story of a duel, where Moggallana challenged and defeated Nandopananda, who was blocking their path.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer! In addition, here is the link of the story in case you want to take a look at it https://www.wisdomlib.org/buddhism/book/maha-prajnaparamita-sastra/d/doc225694.html

Comment: @ruben2020 This question is not just "related" but is a duplicate, isn't it?

Comment: @ChrisW Yes, you're right. It looks duplicate.